# Callback Hell with Promises

Tags: javascript, callback, promise

I got myself stuck in a pyramid of doom using Promises.

I have the following:

- `getA`
- `getB`
- `getC`

`getC` depends on `getB` (and `getA`) that depends on `getA`.

So I must call them like this

```
getA(param)
  .then(getB)
  .then(getC)
```

but, as stated, I need the output of `getA` as a paramater to `getC`, so I did this

```
getA(param)
  .then(function (A) {
    getB(A)
      .then(function (B) {
        getC(A, B)
      });
  });
```

yes, the pyramid got me... I have brought shame upon my family. Help me regain my honor back.

Answer (score 0):

I think You can do like this.

```
var S;
getA(param)
.then(function (A) {
    return S = A;
})
.then(getB)
.then(function (B) {
    return getC(S, B);
})
.then(function (C) {
    console.log(C);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Promise.all to wait for multiple promises :

your pseudo code becomes :

```
var pa = new Promise(function(){/*function A*/});
var pb = new Promise(function(){
    pa.then(function {/*function B*/}
});
Promise.all([pa, pb]).then(function(){/*function C*/});
```

Comment: You need a `return` before `pa.then` or it won't work. Nice idea using Promise.all, but -1 for promise-constrictor anti-pattern. `getA` etc. already return promises,  so there's zero need for constructors.

Comment: Not to mention that you are using the Promise constructor incorrectly. Without calling `resolve` or `reject` the promise will never fulfill.